# AS3 CS5 How can I refresh the stage after a SOUND_COMPLETE?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have an educational game where children hear a sound and then have to choose the correct image out of 3 images.

When they want to hear the sound again they can press a speaker button.
The 3 images are movieclips (named card1, card2 and card3) dynamically added to the stage, with the buttonMode = true.

Whenever they press the speaker to hear the sound again or get feedback if they press the wrong image, I remove the mouse_events from the cards for the duration of the sound. I also set the buttonMode = false, so the children know they won't be able to click while the sound is playing.

On SOUND_COMPLETE I add the eventListeners again. Now the buttonMode = true again as well.

I want to do a refresh of the screen like event.updateAfterEvent(); so the cursor changes to a hand, should they have placed it on one of the cards. BUT the event.updateAfterEvent() can't be attached to a SOUND_COMPLETE, you can only use it after an interaction event like MOUSE or GESTURE.

**tldr; How can I refresh my stage so the cursor changes back to a hand after the SOUND_COMPLETE ?**

Here´s some of the code:

```
    function speakerClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        remLst();
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        cardCnl = gameSnd.play();
        cardCnl.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, sndComplete);
    }
    function sndComplete(event:Event):void
    {
        cardCnl.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, sndComplete);
        addLst();           
    }

    function addLst():void
    {
        for (var i:int = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var card:Card = getChildByName("card" + i) as Card;
            card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fnClick);
            card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, fnOver);
            card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fnOut);
            card.buttonMode = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: on complete remove objects and add them to stage again. This may solve your probelem, not the best but may help.

Comment: If the answer below wouldn't have worked, I'd have gone with your suggestion. My game isn't complicated and it's more important to have it working than to have perfect code. However, TheSHEEP came up with a great answer, so you might want to check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your addLst function, when cycling through the 4 cards, you could check for the current mouse position, and check if it is inside the boundaries of one of the cards.

It could work like this:

```
if ( mouseX > card.x && mouseX < (card.x + card.width)
     mouseY > card.y && mouseY < (card.y + card.height))
{
    Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.BUTTON;
}
```

I am not 100% sure though if buttonMode changes it back to Arrow when the mouse leaves the object. I usually don't use buttonMode.

Comment: This works beautifully :D I started to evade Mouse.cursor because the times I used it, it messed up the mouse behaviour for my buttons.

Comment: Yes, it tends to do that if you do not control it everywhere yourself. But if it works in this case, all the better :)